# Display Friendly Error Message When Html tag is entered in a text Box- MVC ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have requirement of validating user input in a text box. Whenever a html tag is entered it should display the same view with friendly error message like "Cannot enter html tags."

The ways I have tried so far are:

1. [ValidateInput(true)] on the Controller- It comes up with error "Potentially dangerous request"
2. [ValidateInput(false)] on the Controller- It stores the value in the database-(I don't want this)
3. In the view Model I placed a tag for the property `[RegularExpression ( "<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>",ErrorMessage = "You have entered html…Html is not a valid input!" )]`

any one had this this issue. If yes please let me know, how have you fixed that.

Thank you

Comment: What's didn't work about option 3?

Comment: The regular expression should be what your input should match. So you should have the regular expression which does not have `<` or `>`

Comment: It complains about the Regular expression escape sequence-<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>-- Complains about the from last third character '\'-- Error Message Unrecognized escape sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now by displaying the friendly error message. I have changed a little bit by adding Validateinput tag at the Post Action controller.

I have to add this in ViewModel

```
[AllowHtml]
[RegularExpression (@"^[^<>]*$", ErrorMessage = "You have entered html... Html is not a valid input!" )]
public string SomePropertyThatShouldNotAcceptHtml { get; set; }
```

In Action Controller

I have to add the tag in the Post Event

```
[Validateinput(false)]
```

Thanks Darin.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `[AllowHtml]` attribute:

```
[AllowHtml]
[RegularExpression (@"^[^<>]*$", ErrorMessage = "You have entered html... Html is not a valid input!" )]
public string SomePropertyThatShouldNotAcceptHtml { get; set; }
```

Obviously before storing in the database you should ensure that the contents is safe:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(MyViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        // the model is invalid => redisplay view
        return View(model);
    }

    // the model passed validation => store in the database    
    ...
    return RedirectToAction("Success");
}
```

And if you are afraid of XSS you could use the [AntiXSS library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) which will filter out all the dangerous scripts from the HTML. You could even write a custom model binder which will perform this step and automatically assign only a *safe HTML value* to the property.

Comment: It complains about the Regular expression escape sequence-<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>-- Complains about the from last third character '\'-- Error Message Unrecognized escape sequence.

Comment: @StewieFG, I have updated my answer with a new regexp. If you want to use your regexp, you could do this: `[RegularExpression (@"<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>",ErrorMessage = "You have entered html…Html is not a valid input!" )]`. Notice the `@` character in the beginning of the string sequence.

Comment: @StewieFG, the Regex compiles with `@`. If it doesn't work it's probably because it is incorrect. That's another question. I suggested you in my answer a regex which ensures that the input does not contain `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning this looks like an excellent starting point to be able to handle your requirement.  Check out this [article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f9935e/5473/).