# User-friendly message for when user enters html

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, usability

Have an ASP.NET MVC3 app with model validation using [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/). User enters some html in a regular text field, and is presented with a user-friendly error on submit (because of the "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value" error).

What I'd really like to do is show a validation message right on the form itself ("Oops, no html allowed") which shows up right next to the field - similar to model validation errors. That way, the user (malicious or not), knows about it before the entire form is actually filled out and submitted.

Would appreciate any ideas on how to go about implementing this apart from what's shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389704/display-friendly-error-message-when-html-tag-is-entered-in-a-text-box-mvc-asp-n) (i.e. without having to add [AllowHtml] + a regex to almost every field in almost every viewmodel)

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you disallowing HTML? You should just correctly escape your output.

Comment: Because I don't really want users to be adding html to "FirstName" etc (malicious or not) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to write a custom ProertyValidator for server-side FluentValidation with client-side support.  I think you can follow this article, [here](http://blog.sdbarker.com/2011/07/16/enable-custom-fluent-validation-validators-on-the-client-side/), to create client-side jquery validation rule and the adapter.