# Asp Mvc Handling Error when entering HTML in form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

Is it possible to handle the `A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (Model.Title="<p>some text</p>").` system wide? [Answers in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389704/display-friendly-error-message-when-html-tag-is-entered-in-a-text-box-mvc-asp-n) suggest to add some validation on each attribute. I don't want to do that. Is it possible to redirect the user back to the form with an error message telling them they entered invalid input?

**Edit**:
To clarify, I don't want to accept the HTML, I just want to show the user a friendly error message (like the ones for the validation of attributes).

**Edit2**: I know I can add attributes to my properties to allow HTML or disable the validation. Since there are a lot of forms, I don't want to pollute al my properties with `[AllowHtml]` or disable the validation (because I need validation). I'm looking for a way to intercept the MVC-flow and catch this error when it gets triggered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Comment: @greg84: I don't want to accept the input. I just want to know if there is an easy way to catch this specific error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to accept the HTML, I think the only way is to allow the HTML to be submitted, and then check for the presence of any HTML tags server-side. If found, you would then return your user to the form with code like this:

```
if (input.Contains("<")) {
   Model.AddModelError("HTML_FOUND", "There is HTML in your input. Please remove the HTML before trying to submit again");
   return View();
}
```

It's probably possible to implement this system-wide by using a Filter https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28VS.98%29.aspx

Comment: Before entering the controller the error gets thrown so this code is unreachable unless I provide each property with `[AllowHtml]`-attributes (which I don't want to do).

Comment: There it is! I didn't knew about filters. I'll check it out and accept when I got it working. Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

option 1

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

add this on your action,this will disable all field html check.
option 2

```
[AllowHtml]
```

add this on the property you want allow html.this will only allow that property contains html,others not.
but,if you action like

```
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
```

option 2 not work,you must use

```
public ActionResult Index(ModelXXX model)
```

because,this will use the modelbinder,and FormCollection not .