# ASP.NET MVC handling error when entering HTML in form using custom filter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and have to deal with the following challenge: whenever an user tries to input and submit an HTML tag ("<" followed by an alpha character) I get an "Internal Server Error".

Now, I can't use `AllowHtml` and can't disable validation either. I was trying to find a solution that would work system-wide as well.

I found the following ticket, which appears to be same situation I'm in right now: [Asp Mvc Handling Error when entering HTML in form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743712/asp-mvc-handling-error-when-entering-html-in-form)

The solution proposed was to add a custom filter. Seems the right choice to me.

The only problem is: even though I read the suggested link and read some more about filters, I still don't know exactly how to implement this custom filter I want.

Thanks!

Comment: whats the error? is it in post body or request url?

Comment: @Erik - Try encoding the tag before submitting.

Comment: I get a validation error that MVC throws before it even reaches controller. Hence why I want to use my own custom filter.

Comment: And also, I can't disable validation nor allow html.